# What is the order of execution of method calls in a statement

Tags: java

Just something I've been wondering about, and I wanted to understand how the compiler achieves this task.

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = Double.valueOf(sum(1, plusOne(2)));
    }
    
   static int sum(int a, int b) {
       return a+b;
   }
   
   static int plusOne(int a) {
       return ++a;
   }
}
```

Draw your attention to the 3rd line:

```java
double d = Double.valueOf(sum(1, plusOne(2)));
```

My question here is how is this statement executed? Since I'm pretty sure this qualifies as an expression, it should be evaluated left to right I belive.

So my assumption would be that the Double.valueOf() is called first. However, now I'm passing in the method call sum() as the argument to the valueOf() method, and it's output will serve as the input to valueOf().

As this is happening would we assume that the execution of valueOf() is paused as the sum() method is evaluated? Similarly when sum() is executed and plusOne() is used as the second argument of sum(), is it also paused as plusOne() is evaluated?

I hope my question makes sense. It's just basically what is the order of evaluation here, and what is  happening in-between? Are the execution of methods being "paused" whilst an argument for a method is being evaluated? Or is something different going on? Perhaps even the inner statements are being evaluated first? Is plusOne() evaluated first, then sum() then valueOf()? I doubt it but I'm here trying to find out

Any help to answer this question + any links to some further reading material would be very appreciated.

Comment: The inner statements are evaluated first, as you pointed out you use the value returned from the inner statements later in Double.valueOf().
It will be the same if you rewrite your code and put the value of plusOne(2) and sum(1, plusOne(2)) in a variable before calling Doubel.valueOf();

Comment: Try to use a debugger to better understand such things. Any IDE has debugging features builtin.

Comment: @user16320675 Thank you very much for the JLS 15.12.4 reference. Reading it gave me a lot of insight on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to invoke `Double.valueOf`, we need the value of its argument, i.e. `sum(1, plusOne(2))`. So we try to invoke `sum`. But we need the arguments, i.e. `1` (no problem there) and `plusOne(2)`.

So what is actually invoked first is `plusOne(2)`, with result `3`, then we invoke `sum(1, 3)` with result `4`, and finally `Double.valueOf(4)`.

So while expressions in general are evaluated left-to-right, arguments to any single expression need to be evaluated before the expression itself can be evaluated. So it would be more complete to call it "left-to-right-innermost-to-outermost" evaluation order.

As a more complete example:

`foo(bar()) + baz(boo())`

The execution order would be:

1. bar  -- left innermost
2. foo  -- left outermost
3. boo  -- right innermost
4. baz  -- right outermost

Answer (score 0):

Like in maths:

1. plusOne(2) => 3
2. sum(1, 3) => 4
3. Double.valueOf(4) => 4.0
4. double d = 4.0